# cant set Index ObjectChoiceField (load slow json)

Tags: json, blackberry

I have a select that I get Json post with http, but I try to sets initially selected index but there is nothing in the list do not select anything. because the json is great.

```
public AppMainScreen() {    
    loadLists();
    MySelect = new ObjectChoiceField( "Select: ", new Object[0], 3 );
    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
    vfm.add(MySelect);
    add(vfm);
}
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive, i.e. what do you mean by `there is nothing in the list do not select anything`?

Comment: yes, Here I ask the list to select the index 3
MySelect = new ObjectChoiceField( "Select: ", new Object[0],3);
but when I add the select even no any data, it takes a few seconds to get the list data from JSON.
understand what I mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement appears wrong to me:

```
new ObjectChoiceField( "Select: ", new Object[0],3);
```

The second parameter to this constructor is supposed to be an array of objects whose .toString() method will be used to populate the choices. In this case, you have given it a 0 length array, i.e. no Objects.  So there is nothing to choose.  And then you have asked it to automatically select the 3rd item, and of course there is no 3rd item.

You should correct the code to actually supply an object array.

One option to make it easy is have your JSON load actually create a String array with one entry per selectable item.  Then you use the index selected to identify the chosen item.